# ASP.NET: Identity_Insert set to OFF - How do I fix this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**My error is as follows:**

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Snacks' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Snacks' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I have created a table with an SQL Database that has a unique ID, description and price option with the primary key being the ID.

How do I fix this error in Visual Web Developer 2010?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsSnacks" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cs3201 %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Snacks] WHERE [SID] = @SID" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Snacks] ([Price], [Description]) VALUES (@Price, @Description)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Price], [Description], [SID] FROM [Snacks]" 

        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Snacks] SET [Price] = @Price, [Description] = @Description WHERE [SID] = @SID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="SID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="SID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>`
```

Comment: This is a SQL error, not specifically a ASP.NET one.  Do you have a specific SQL query that you're running that you can show us?

Comment: Not that I know of, is there a way to check? I'm a beginner.

Comment: What technology are you using? Something (either you or the tools you're using) is creating an `INSERT` command, which is attempting to set a value for an `identity` column.  Either alter the query so it doesn't, or (as people have answer) used `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` for the specific table

Comment: I am using Visual-Web-Developer 2010 with Asp.Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specifically an ASP.NET issue, it's a SQL error.

When you have an `identity` column, every time a new row is added, that column should contain a new value (normally incremented by 1).

The error your showing is because either you or the technology you're using is attempting to tell SQL Server what value should be in that `identity` column.

You have the following options available to you (that I'm aware of)...

**If you wrote the SQL query and listed all the columns** then you should remove the `identity` column.  For instance...

```
INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] ([IDENTCOLUMN],[MYVAL]) VALUES (1,1)
```

Should become...

```
INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] ([MYVAL]) VALUES (1)
```

**If you wrote the SQL query and did NOT list all the columns** then you should write all the columns without the `identity` column.  For instance...

```
INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] VALUES (1,1)
```

Should become...

```
INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] ([MYVAL]) VALUES (1)
```

**Otherwise, if you actually want to specifically set the value of the `identity` column** you need to tell SQL Server that you're overriding the normal `identity` processing by using the following...

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MYTABLE] ON
INSERT INTO [MYTABLE] ([IDENTCOLUMN],[MYVAL]) VALUES (1,1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MYTABLE] OFF
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but I didn't write any code for this part. I added the table, configured the data source and then manually entered the 3 columns into the table.

Comment: Looking at your updated question, I have to admit your `INSERT` command looks fine, as you're definitely not setting [SID] in there.  Very strange

Comment: Can you show us in your question the `CREATE TABLE` for `[Snacks]` so we can confirm exactly what the columns are?

Comment: I think this did the trick! I am now curious how to get my details view to appear as "empty template" rather than have my first selection in the dv when I load the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a completely different issue, so please create a new question.  How did my answer help you, what was the issue?  Please remember SO runs under a system of [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation). If my answer was helpful, please consider [upvoting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/188605). If my answer was the solution to your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/188605) - which shows the community that your question has been answered.

Comment: Thanks freefaller, and please do the same so I can eventually get into the chatrooms.

Comment: You're now over 15 (+7, 2 for marking the answer and 5 for the question).  Thanks for marking my answer as the correct one.  Can I ask what you did to fix the error?

Comment: I added a WHERE clause to my SQL database / Connection String that added @@'s in front of my unique ID so that the first selection was read as null and displayed the "Add new item" Empty template rather than the error message.

Answer (score 0):

you need to SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON:

Syntax is:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . ] table { ON | OFF }
```

Comment: Where do I insert this?

Comment: before your insert query.

Answer (score 0):

You specified your ID column to be Identity in your database. After that you're trying to insert a specific value to that column which is most likely something you don't want to do.

Remove the value for ID in your ASP.NET code when inserting, it will be auto-generated for you.

Comment: Would that be "Identity Seed: 1" ?

Comment: No that's the first number that will be generated for you. Please post a code where you're trying to add the data and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I don't have reputation to post photos yet and I am using Visual Web Developer

Comment: I pasted what I think you need above!

Comment: That is helpful, but it doesn't seem to do the identity insert unless your columns Price or Description are defined as Identity in your database. If you're not sure post the code that defined your table.

Comment: @user3405335 After looking at your code it seems that you have defined wrong column as Identity in your database. Please check that only [SID] column has Identity set to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

I got that error after inserting an object with id number that already exists inside the db. Happened while inserting from an asp.net project to code first approach db.
Just an idea to check off before trying the more complicated suggestions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30713604)